# Shorten Labels f.e. only first letters

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot a PCA but because of overlapping labels the species names aren't really readable anymore. Is there an option to make it more clear? For example using first letters?

PCA plot vegetation science:

[image: ot]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `abbreviate` (and [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2)).

PCA

```
p <-  prcomp(USArrests, scale=TRUE)
```

Plot

```
library(ggbiplot) 
library(ggrepel)
p1 <- ggbiplot(p) + 
       geom_text_repel(aes(label = rownames(USArrests)))
p2 <- ggbiplot(p) + 
       geom_text_repel(aes(label = abbreviate(rownames(USArrests), minlength = 1)))

library(patchwork)
p1 + p2 # compare the two plots
```

[image]

---

Using `base R`

```
biplot(p, xlabs = abbreviate(rownames(USArrests), minlength = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: @SaraHelsen If the solution worked for you consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark next to vote button. Best